# Objective Function formula for price arbitrage strategies

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to come up with a method and objective function to use for the determination of an optimal charge-discharge profile of a battery to aribitrage energy prices.

Currently, my code uses `scipy.optimize.minimize` to find an optimale charge-discharge profile to maximise **profit**, not a **Net Present Value (NPV)** figure, which  I am interested in.

Let me explain more thoroughly the conceptual problem I see.
Whereas it is easy to express a profit objective function for each optimisation horizon passed in the `scipy.optimize.minimize` as so:

```
def obj_fun(x): 
    cost = np.sum(x * dt * opt_price)
    return cost
```

and minimise the cost, or maximizing the profit, it much harder to do the same for an NPV figure.
Indeed, the number of actualisation periods (ie, the number of operational years) of cash flows brought in by the battery depends on the number of cycles the battery performs.
This is because the operating lifetime of the battery may be limited by either the cycles life or the calendar life. The maximum cycle life may be hit before the calendar life if the number of cycles is high, thus limiting the operating life, and finally influencing the calculation of the NPV figure.

In a nutshell, here is the problem at hand:
Before running the optimisation, we don't know which form the Objetive function will take, since the operation of the battery will influence the number of years.

I have thought of splitting the optimisation in two, one for each operating life. However, there remains the problem that, under the maximum cycles life case, one does not know how many years the battery will run, since that depends on the charging profile, which is equivalent to the solution.

Do you believe this is the right tool? Where could I find more info on this?

Thanks!

I have implemented an optimisation program for the profit only, not the NPV, as so:

```
def obj_fun(x): 
    cost = np.sum(x * dt * opt_price)
    return cost
  
# function of the actual energy content of the storage
def fun_E_storage(x): 
    #pre-allocation of variables
    P_charg = np.zeros(x.shape)
    P_discharg = np.zeros(x.shape)
    
    #get charging and discharging of storage: (-)discharging, (+)charging
    idx_charg = x > 0
    idx_discharg = x < 0    
    P_charg[idx_charg] = x[idx_charg] 
    P_discharg[idx_discharg] = x[idx_discharg]
    
    #calculate energy content of storage; consider efficiency for charging and discharging
    #energy per time step dt
    E_storage_dt = P_charg * dt  + P_discharg * dt 
    #cumulative energy over optimization horizon
    E_storage = np.cumsum(E_storage_dt) + E0_0
    return E_storage

#Revenues
#%% main


#storage specifications
spec_Pminmax = 20 # (MW) min./max (discharging/charging) power of storage; both directions assumed equal
spec_Emax = 80 # (MWh) storage capacity
spec_eta = 0.8 # (pu) efficiency
spec_E0 = 40 # (MWh) initial energy content; 0 <= spec_E0 <= spec_Emax

#optimization specifications
opt_horizon = 168 # (h) optimization horizon for which optimizations are carried out
opt_period = 3*168 #17280 # (h) overall optimization period; full year = 8760 hours
    
#particion the prices into a list according to the optimization horizon and optimization period
mod = int(np.floor(opt_period/opt_horizon))
length = mod * opt_horizon
opt_price_length = np.array(price_full[0:length])
opt_price_horizon = (np.reshape(opt_price_length,(int(len(opt_price_length)/opt_horizon),opt_horizon)))
opt_price_horizon = list(opt_price_horizon)
delta = opt_period - length
if delta > 0:
    opt_price_horizon.append(np.array(price_full[length+1:length+1+delta]))

#price vector of full optimizaton period
opt_price_fullperiod = np.concatenate((opt_price_length, np.array(price_full[length+1:length+1+delta])))


Pres = []
#optimization loops through each horizon within all hours
for i in range(len(opt_price_horizon)):
    #set the initial energy storage content
    if i==0:
        E0_0 = spec_E0
    
    opt_price = opt_price_horizon[i] / np.max(opt_price_horizon[i]) #price of optimization horizon i
    E_const = scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint(fun_E_storage, 0, spec_Emax) # storage energy constraint
    bounds = scipy.optimize.Bounds(-spec_Pminmax, spec_Pminmax) # storage power constraints
    x0 = np.ones(opt_price.shape) * ((-1)*(opt_price-np.mean(opt_price)))/np.max(opt_price)/10 # initial condition np.zeros(opt_price.shape)
    x0[x0<0] = 0
    res = scipy.optimize.minimize(obj_fun, x0, bounds = bounds, constraints = E_const, method='SLSQP', options={'maxiter': 10000, 'ftol' : 1e-3, 'eps': 1e-3, 'disp' : True}) #, 'eps': 1e-07, 'ftol': 1e-06, 'disp':False})#,     method='trust-constr', options={'maxiter': 1000, 'xtol':1e-4, 'verbose':1})
    if res.success == False:
        print(res.message)
        
    # SOC after each horizon is input for the next horizon
    opt_E_charg = np.zeros(opt_price.shape)
    opt_E_discharg = np.zeros(opt_price.shape)
    opt_E_charg[res.x > 0] = res.x[res.x > 0]*dt
    opt_E_discharg[res.x < 0] = res.x[res.x < 0]*dt
    opt_E_storage = np.cumsum(opt_E_charg+opt_E_discharg)+E0_0
    opt_SOC = (opt_E_storage/spec_Emax)*100 
    E0_0=(opt_SOC[-1]/100)*spec_Emax
    
    if np.min(opt_SOC) < -10**-2:
        print(np.min(opt_SOC))
    elif np.max(opt_SOC) > 100.01:
        print(np.max(opt_SOC))
    
    #collect optimization results for storage power
    Pres = Pres + list(res.x)
```